# Eigenvalue and Eigenmatrix of a 3D Tensor - How to calculate it?

Tags: eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra, tensor

How to calculate easily the eigenmatrix of a 3D tensor.

I try immersing the tensor in a big matrix, in my case, the tensor is of nxnxn and I can build an n^2 x n^2 matrix that contains all the "coefficients" of my original tensor, but my calculations give me more eigenvalues that I have in my original problem (n^2).

There exist any numerical library for eigenvalues/eigenmatrices of a tensor?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to specify how you define these eigenvalues and eigenmatrices? There are multiple definitions of eigenvalues of a tensor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask for the eigenvalues of an $m=3$-order $n$-dimensional tensor $M$. There is no unique definition of the "eigenvalue" $\lambda$ for $m\geq 3$. One frequently used definition is
$$\sum_{i_2,i_3,\ldots i_m=1}^n M_{i,i_2,i_3,\ldots i_m}x_{i_2}x_{i_3}\cdots x_{i_m}=\lambda x_i^{m-1}, \;\;\text{for all}\;\;i=1,2,\ldots n$$
The problem of computing the eigenvalues for $m\geq 3$ is NP-hard, see [All Real Eigenvalues of Symmetric Tensors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3720) (2014). A treatment specifically for $m=3$ is in [A Spectral Theory for Tensors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2923) (2010) and in the [Wikipedia article on higher-order singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition). Algorithms are part of the [MatLab toolbox.](https://www.tensortoolbox.org/hosvd_doc.html)